# How do you use Kaminari to paginate a page by a number value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

I've set up Kaminari so that it can accurately paginate by post title if i do this:

```
def index
...
@posts = Post.order('title').page(params[:page]).per(5)
...
end
```

i also have <% paginate %> in the view

but if I try something like this

```
@posts = Post.order('pageviews').page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

it stops working. There are no bugs or errors, but it just appears to be sorted arbitrarily. Possibly by date. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, is it correctly sorted without Kaminari?
I mean, how is `Post.order('pageviews')` sorted?

Next, can you check the output SQL?
How is it sorted if you run

```
Post.order('pageviews').page(1).to_sql
```

result on your DB console?

Comment: ah, it's sorted correctly now. for some reason, the pageview values were not saving.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need `desc` at order clause? because currently it will order 0 views first.

```
 Post.order('pageviews desc')
```